Persistent notifications
I am a relative new Ubuntu user and use it in my work. I also use Slack installed in Ubuntu. The problem is that I often miss notifications from Slack.
Slack messages is shown as messages at top for some seconds and then disappear.
Is it possible to change it so new messages stay there until I manually close them ?
Or at least change timeout value to a very long time.
It is often said that Linux is more flexible than Windows and you can tweak it what ever I want.

It seems not possible to change it. I found this https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=783719

Linux is indeed. Gnome3 on the other hand not so ;) I would assume you need to add an extension to the panel. Cinnamon and Budgie (is gnome2 ...) have a notification applet that changes color if there are unseen notifications.

Have a look at these 3: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1526/notification-centerselenium-h/    https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/41/permanent-notifications/   https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3795/notification-timeout/
